# the cedet from bzr can't autoload, seems it get the wrong path

Tags: emacs, cedet

the output is as followed:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Opening output file" "no such file or directory" "/users/name/files/emacs-23.4/lisp")
  write-region(";;; lisp --- automatically extracted autoloads\n;;\n;;; Code:\n\n\f\n(provide 'lisp)\n;; Local Variables:\n;; version-control: never\n;; no-byte-compile: t\n;; no-update-autoloads: t\n;; coding: utf-8\n;; End:\n;;; lisp ends here\n" nil "/users/name/files/emacs-23.4/lisp")
  autoload-ensure-default-file("/users/name/files/emacs-23.4/lisp")
  update-directory-autoloads()
  apply(update-directory-autoloads nil)
  batch-update-autoloads()
  command-line-1(("--eval" "(setq debug-on-error t)" "-l" "../../../cedet-remove-builtin.el" "-L" "../" "--eval" "(progn (require (quote cedet-compat)) (require (quote mode-local)))" "-L" "../../eieio/" "-L" "../" "-L" "../" "--eval" "(progn  (setq generated-autoload-file \"\"))" "-f" "batch-update-autoloads"))
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()

make[1]: *** [autoloads] Error 255
```

the cedets files are under /users/name/go/cedet, why it would goto /users/name/files/emacs-23.4? This directory is not existed.
I have tried "make clean-all", and execute "bzr revert" and "bzr clean", but the result is the same.
Can anyone help?

Comment: which version of emacs are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that it's trying to load CEDET from GNU Emacs. Please, use `make clean-all && make` to compile CEDET from bzr, and then put loading of CEDET from bzr to the top of your `~/.emacs` file.

Comment: Hi Alex, I update the error. it seems autoload not generate the files. I have done "make clean-all && make", the problem still exists.

Comment: can you do following - `make clean-all`, and after that `make 2>&1 > build.log` and send this file to me (alexott at gmail dot com), together with more details about your system: OS version, etc.

Comment: Hi Alex, Seems the development version can't still not compile passed in my desktop with command 'make'. Is it ok to use the cedet-build.el ?

Comment: The phenomenon is the same as my description in question when using the command "make". I don't know where emacs find the path "/users/name/files/emacs-23.4/lisp", I do not have this path, and the autoloads are not created correctly.

Comment: Due to some reason, I have an very old emacs in system and I can't remove it.I think this impact my new emacs 23.4 and cedet from bzr, can you told me how to get rid of the impact of old emacs version?

Comment: can you try to compile with `make clean-all; make EMACS="emacs -q"`

Comment: Hello Alex, the problem is solved. Root cause is that the version of program "make" on my system is 3.80, it does not support the command "abspath" which is used in Makefile, so the compile process stops and give the above error.